/dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid argument (921600)
I wanted to debug my linux kernel program using KGDB, but the following error occurred while configuring the debug serial port using GDB.
(gdb) set serial baud 921600

(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0

warning: Invalid baud rate 921600.  Maximum value is 460800.

/dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid argument.

I have already used minicom to communicate with the development board, and the baud rate of 921600 can be used.
So is this maximum limit the reason for GDB? How to modify it?
GDB version:
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.1

ubuntu version：
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-124-generic

